# Assumptions in Young integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Are the following statement (A) and (B) equivalent?

(A) Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function defined for all $0\le t<\infty$,
and is such that

1. $f(0) =0$,
2. $f$ is continuous for $0\le t <\infty$ (from the right, at $t = 0$),
3. $f$ is strictly increasing for $0\le t<\infty$, and $\lim_{t\to\infty}=\infty$.

(B) Suppose that $f$ is an increasing bijection $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$

My thoughts: bijection implies strictly (increasing); surjectivity+increasing implies continuity; f(0) must be 0, otherwise we lose surjectivity; (3) also follows from surjectivity